# How do you count objects (using ultrasonic sensor HCSR04) as 1, after they leave the trigger/echo path?

Tags: arduino-uno, hc-sr04

I found a simple code online that meets my goal to almost 100%, however when I place my hand in front of it, the number continues to count. I am trying to only count "1" when the solid object has moved from initial view of the sensor, to ending view.

```
#define trigPin 13
#define echoPin 12
int counter = 0;
int currentState = 0;
int previousState = 0;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin (9600);
 pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 long duration, distance;
 digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 
 delayMicroseconds(2); 
 digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
 delayMicroseconds(10); 
 digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
 duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
 distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;
 if (distance <= 10){ 
 currentState = 1;
 }
 else {
```

Comment: Your code is missing some part at the end. Maybe thats just a copy paste error. Please provide the full code

Comment: it's the same thing as counting the number of times a light has been turned on ....you don't count 1 every time the light is on when you look at it ... there is something else that you have to see before you can say that the light was just turned on